# Get day of week in Pyspark 3 using date format

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0, spark3

In my old `Spark2.X` code, I had a following line

```
pageviewsDF.groupBy( date_format(col("capturedAt"), "u-E").alias("Day Of Week") ).sum('req')
```

That will give `Day of Week` as `1-Mon, 2-Tue` etc.

But now in `Spark3` I get an error that `u-E` not recognised and I can use legacy setting as below

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")
```

But is there a way to get same output without using legacy setting?

Comment: you can revert to default setting after the usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `expr` expression to generate the desired format.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

...
pageviewsDF.groupBy(F.expr('concat(dayofweek(capturedAt), "-", date_format(capturedAt, "E"))').alias("Day Of Week")).sum('req')
```